# Anise, Pepper, Cinnamon, Cloves and Fennel better known?

Tags: spices

How is the combination of Anise, Pepper, Cinnamon, Cloves and Fennel better known?

Comment: I'm not sure how this question is useful and why you would think that a combination of spices has a name. If the question was the other way around (what is in Chinese Five Spice Powder), it would be more logical in my eyes.

Answer (score 3):

That would be better known as Chinese Five Spice Powder. Do I win the steak knives?

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking about [Chinese Five Spice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-spice_powder), which sometimes has these ingredients, assuming pepper refers to [Szchaun Peppercorn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sichuan_pepper)?